# Permission denied while trying to configure ODBC drivers

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

I was following the instructions in [this](http://mysqlworkbench.org/2012/11/set-up-and-configure-postgresql-odbc-drivers-for-the-mysql-workbench-migration-wizard/) page (for linux).

My goal is to migrate Postgre SQL (musicbrainz data base) to My SQL for a project I'm working on.
The problem is that when I'm trying to execute this line (according to the instructions):

`$> ./configure --with-iodbc --enable-pthreads`

I get this error:

`bash: ./configure: Permission denied`

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You downloaded the tar ball (psqlODBC) like it says in the link?  Extract the files.  The `configure` script should be executable already.  On my system, I got `-rwxr-xr-x`.

Otherwise, make it executable with:  `chmod 755 ./configure`

Then try again.

Comment: Yes I think downloaded the tar ball, isn't it the last link in the page for example.

Comment: The instructions page you linked in your question has the command `./configure ...` twice.  On both occasions is mentions, just before, to download psqlODBC from a link.  In that link, yes you should download the highest version available.